# Git can't access SSH key after every laptop restart

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-agent

So I have set up SSH key on my Ubuntu 20.04 with [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent). The problem is that every time I restart my machine and try to use the SSH key with `git pull` or some command that requires SSH auth it says permission denied.

To fix that temporarely I just run these two commands:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

What is the permanent fix for this so I don't have to run these two commands every time I want to use the SSH key for Git?

Answer (score 0):

It will not completely fix it, but adding those lines to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc or which shell rc you are using.
Will fix it without you having to do it, it is not proper fix but it should work as a workaround.

Comment: Sure I'll try it. I'll see if it works next time I restart and I'll give feedback here. Thanks!